# compiling errors for rgbdslam hydro for kinect

Tags: ros, rgbdslamv2, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

```
    Currently I am testing the rgbdslam version 2 following the procedures on this webpage: http://felixendres.github.io/rgbdslam_v2/

   As I reinstalled Ubuntu12.04 and hydro. It works well therefore I don't think there is problem on ubuntu and hydro. 

   Everything goes well after $ rosdep install rgbdslam  as it displays #All required rosdeps installed successfully!

   Then I would like to build the rgbdslamv2 and went to my catkine workspace and execute "catkin_make"
   It displayed the following:

   ####
```

##### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/lili/catkin_ws/build"

##### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/lili/catkin_ws/build"

[  7%] Built target rgbdslam_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Performing build step for 'siftgpu_proj'
make[3]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add `+' to parent make rule.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGLEW
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [siftgpu] Error 1
make[2]: *** [rgbdslam_v2/external/siftgpu_prefix/src/siftgpu_proj-stamp/siftgpu_proj-build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [rgbdslam_v2/external/CMakeFiles/siftgpu_proj.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: INTERNAL: Exiting with 5 jobserver tokens available; should be 4!
Invoking "make" failed

**What's the problem?** Thank you so much for your advice!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162376/compiling-errors-for-rgbdslam-hydro-for-kinect/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2014-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20167/amine/) on 2015-02-04**:
This code is not compiling. When doing catkin_make I get the following error:

/tmp/ccyMrTtU.s: Assembler messages: /tmp/ccyMrTtU.s:16629: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 88(%rsp),%xmm1,%xmm2'

/tmp/ccyMrTtU.s:16639: Error: no such instruction: `vfmadd312ss 96(%rsp),%xmm3,%xmm1'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Download OpenGL extension wrapper library.
Here is the link:- http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html
Go into the directory of downloaded package glew
do "sudo make install"
And then again try catkin_make RGBDSLAM. It should work out

---

Originally posted by [Himil Sheth](https://answers.ros.org/users/18755/himil-sheth/) with karma: 16 on 2014-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0